# Using CLLocationManager right after requestAlwaysAuthorization

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have a question concerning CLLocationManager. Right after asking for permission I want to use the locationServices immediately. 
My code in viewDidLoad: looks like this:

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    [self locationServicesAreNotEnabled];
}
else
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    {
        NSLog(@"Location Services unavailable denied/restricted");
    }
    else if (authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    if (authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
    {
        [self startStandardUpdates];
    }
}
```

`

It seems like the code hits the line [_location Manager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; and then, without waiting for the answer of the user, continues with the next if statement. 
How can I wait for the user's respond and only afterwards call

```
if (authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
```

? Can I achieve that by using a block?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`. It will be called as soon as you get authorization, and you can then proceed immediately to use the location manager.

You can in fact store a block (saying what you want to do as soon as you get authorization) as a property in advance, and that way when `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` is called, you can look to see whether you've stored the block, and if you have, you call it.

Comment: Actual example code is provided in my book, and is also available here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift The code is in Swift but the structure applies equally to Objective-C.

Comment: Simple answer and perfectly working, just how it's supposed to be :) Should have noticed the delegation method myself though. Thanks a lot matt!